# mvc read hidden field within the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, hidden-field

I am doing an MVC Application.

I have a View with differents Partial View on it.

In the first `partial View` I have de User ID in a `Hidden Field`, if the User is logged.

My First Partial View inherit like this

> @model Prj.Models.UserLoginModel

The Model is like this..

```html
 public class UserLoginModel
    {
        public long User_id { get; set; }
        public bool Keep { get; set; }
        public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
   
    }
```

and I have a Hidden field

> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.User_id)

The other Partial View, is a `IEnumerable` used to render a `PagedList`

It Inherit from

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Prj.Models.CommentModel>
```

```html
    public class CommentModel
    {
        public long Upload_id { get; set; }
        public long User_id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
      }
```

In the View I need to validate both User from Models.

```html
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    ask item.User_id == PartialView1.Hidden.User_id
 }
```

My question is if it si posible to read it or I have to include the User Id in the Model of the second Partial View?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a model on the main view that has child-models for the partial views, and they get passed in like the following:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("partial", Model.PartialViewModel); }
```

You could instead pass in the parent model:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("partial", Model); }
```

And then have access to all of the properties on the parent, as well as any child models:

```
Model.PartialViewModel.UserID
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are different models.. One model have the User Id and the Picture and the second model has a IEnumerable<Comments> render in a PagedList. I need to know if the User Logged is the same person who wrote any of the comments

Comment: That wasn't very evident from your question. Perhaps you want to elaborate a bit more by adding your models and more of your View's code.

Comment: I add more comments.. to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Partial views are different HTML pages and as such are not aware of each other's elements. AFTER they are rendered you get one big HTML page with content from all partial views which could be accessed through javascript

If you want partial views to share variables then you need to either pass a model that contains the variable to both partial views OR use something in javascript $(document).ready on the main HTML page that will send your hidden field value from the field in one partial view to another

EDIT - i see you said below that both are different view models. One thing you can also do is create a baseviewmodel with a userId variable.. and then have both of your view models inherit from the baseviewmodel and that way you will have your variable in both - example - https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/aspnet-mvc-model-make-a-baseviewmodel-for-your-layouts-PX